# Is there a way to use Acrobat Reader in Perl to save multiple PDF files as HTML files?

Tags: html, perl, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I am using [Xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/) for extracting text from PDF files which works well with `-raw` option, but now we want to convert the PDF files to HTML files for extracting the HTML formating tags like bold <b>, italics <i> etc with the text. Xpdf with the `-html` option does work, I have also tried using pdf2html for this but did not find it reliable as tags like <sup> and <sub> where missing.

We are now using Acrobat Reader to save the PDF files as HTML files which gives us all the HTML formatting tags.

Is there a way to use Acrobat Reader in Perl to save multiple PDF files as HTML files?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need to do this from Perl, or would anything that can control an external application work?

Comment: It need not be in Perl, any other application would do. The only thing is that it should be able to convert multiple files.

Answer (score 2):

PDF styling information is completely arbitrary and can't be reliably mapped to HTML in any meaningful way. One strategy that I've had some luck with is to use the `-xml` option to `pdftohtml` and then use [LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/~pajas/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) to apply some heuristics to the output and come up with a reasonable HTML approximation of the original document.